# ruby won't start or stop with upstart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm, upstart

The wrapper script works standalone but I can't stop or start the process via upstart.  The ubuntu stop and start hangs and I have expect daemon on for pid tracking since it has it's own pid file.

/etc/init/tracks.conf:

```
start on runlevel [2345] and started networking
stop on runlevel [!2345] or stopped networking

author "Root <root@localhost>"

description "tracks wrapper for upstart"

expect daemon

exec sudo -u ubuntu /usr/local/bin/tracks >> /home/ubuntu/tracks/log/upstart.log 2>&1

respawn
respawn limit 1 10
```

The /usr/local/bin/tracks wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
export rvmsudo_secure_path=1
cd /home/ubuntu/tracks && /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvmsudo bundle exec rails server -e production -p 80 -d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it in /etc/init/tracks.conf

```
start on runlevel [2345] and started networking
stop on runlevel [!2345] or stopped networking

author "Root <root@localhost>"

description "tracks wrapper for upstart"

chdir /home/ubuntu/tracks

pre-start script
    exec sudo -u ubuntu "/usr/local/bin/tracks"
end script

post-stop exec kill -9 `cat /home/ubuntu/tracks/tmp/pids/server.pid`
```